# What is the difference between debug and compile?

Tags: .net

What is the difference between debug and compile?

How do I compile an application without debugging in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Compile is the act of turning human-readable code into code the machine can understand and execute.

Debug is the act of finding out where in the code the application is going wrong (debug = get rid of bugs.)

In the context of an IDE, compile (Build in Visual Studio) just builds the code, debug (Run in Visual Studio) compiles the code, launches it and attaches a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

"Compile" only builds the application, but "Debug" compiles it and launches it for debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Debugging is the process of removing bugs from the code, typically by stepping through code to identify the bug. A tool that helps one step through code is called a debugger. A debug build is one that has symbols to allow the developer to step through lines of source code while executing.

Compiling is the process of turning code into machine instructions (or some kind of intermediate language, or bytecode, etc). A tool that does this is called a compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Compiling the code generates the IL code, and debugging is stepping into the code at run-time where it is converted from IL code to machine language.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the menu item "Build -> Build Solution" or press F6. This will build(Compile) the solution without entering debug mode.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Debugging is a part of compilation which can't happen without compilation i.e., converting the whole thing into machine language. So if the compiler finds a problem in compiling then the debugger helps in removing it to complete the compilation.